# Bandpass Filter Order vs Sample Numbers of Noisy Signal

Tags: matlab, filters, bandpass, window

I'm working on signal filtering in MATLAB. i wrote sample code that generate 50 Hz signal with some noisy frequency and use Kaiser bandpass filter to get only 50Hz frequency. this code work great! but there is a big problem!

**Sample Rate is 2000 Hz** and **Filter Order is about 39000** , and my **signal length is 50000 samples**! in other hand i have to **wait about 25 seconds** to gathering my signal! that is too long time!, if i decrease signal length ( to about 6000 samples ) filter result is so noisy because of filter order. if i decrease filter order , filter signal result is too noisy too! the best time that i cloud wait for gathering data is about 3 seconds.

**is there any way to get same result with 6000 samples of signal and high order filter? ( 39000 )**

thanks.

```
Fs = 2000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 50000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector

Hd =  KAISERFilter;

for i=1:50

a = 5;
b = 500;
r1 = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1);
r2 = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1);
r3 = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1);
r4 = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1);

n = r1 *sin(2*pi*49.2*t) + r2 *sin(2*pi*50.5*t) + 0.1 * randn(size(t)) +  r3 *sin(2*pi*15.5*t) +  r4 *sin(2*pi*110*t) ;
x = 30 *sin(2*pi*50*t); % main frequency
y = x+n;


subplot(2,1,1);
plot(y)
title('Signal')
xlabel('time (milliseconds)');

yf = filter(Hd.Numerator,1,y);
```

and Kaiser filter code is :

```
function Hd = KieserFilter

% All frequency values are in Hz.
Fs = 2000;  % Sampling Frequency

Fstop1 = 49.5;              % First Stopband Frequency
Fpass1 = 49.9;            % First Passband Frequency
Fpass2 = 50.1;            % Second Passband Frequency
Fstop2 = 50.5;              % Second Stopband Frequency
Dstop1 = 1e-06;           % First Stopband Attenuation
Dpass  = 0.057501127785;  % Passband Ripple
Dstop2 = 1e-06;           % Second Stopband Attenuation
flag   = 'scale';         % Sampling Flag

% Calculate the order from the parameters using KAISERORD.
[N,Wn,BETA,TYPE] = kaiserord([Fstop1 Fpass1 Fpass2 Fstop2]/(Fs/2), [0 ...
                             1 0], [Dstop1 Dpass Dstop2]);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
b  = fir1(N, Wn, TYPE, kaiser(N+1, BETA), flag);
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a time frequency uncertainty in estimation problem.  It takes longer than 3 seconds for there to be enough information in a signal to tell the difference between 3 clearly separated sinewaves between 49 and 51 Hz, and only 1 fat (slightly modulated) one.  And you can't filter out a signal unless there is enough information to tell whether it's even there or not.

Comment: Thanks, I working on vibration sensor, and it's data is too noisy, i need that filter an special frequency, this frequency about 49.8 to  50.2 and my bandpass filter bandwidth in too norraw, because if I increase bandwith other environment signals effect on my main signal. But my big problem is that maximum sampling time about 4 secondes, my sampling rate is 2000 Herz. What is your idea for filtering?

Comment: Is there any suggestions?

Comment: @AlirezaIzadimehr note that hotpaw2 just explained that no matter where your data comes from, your frequency estimation can't work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some tutorials which you may need to refer.  Zero phase filtering adjust the time delay produced by digital filters.

[zero phase filtering to remove noises from signal](https://youtu.be/7AD21oV-PyU)

50 Hz and 60 Hz power hum removal from signals.

https://youtu.be/iwR1QIspjM8

[high frequency noise removal tutorials in matlab](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc2rvfiptPSQT3NBfCv9piRo4CvpsGJf4)